# Spring Boot + MySQL docker containers

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, docker

I have two containers, one with a Srping app and another with mysql. When I run the Spring app on my local machine, it successfully connects to my MySQL db running in a docker container. Once I spin up the Spring container I get a connection error, the app is unable to communicate with the MySQL container. How do I configure the Spring container to communicate with the db container? I've tried creating a bridge network to no avail. I believe my issue is `spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3309/library` but when I try with the network id the jar fails to build `spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://lms-network/library`. I've been following [this](https://www.javainuse.com/devOps/docker/docker-mysql) tutorial. docker [image](https://hub.docker.com/repository/docker/joshuad23/spring-docker).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple of ways we can solve it.

### Using docker-compose

Put both the containers in docker-compose file. Example:

```yaml
version: "3"
services: 
  spring-boot-service:
    build:
      context: .
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    environment:
      DB_HOST: mysql-db
      DB_NAME: library
      DB_USER: <user>
      DB_PASSWORD : <pwd>


  mysql-db:
    image: mysql
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "root"
      MYSQL_DATABASE: <db_name>
      #... other properties
```

then in application.properties, use connection string as :
`spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://${DB_HOST}:3306/${DB_NAME}`

then use `docker-compose up` to run both containers together. This way they will share network through docker-compose.

### Using host.docker.internal

When you run your spring boot app and mysql in separate containers, you can't refer the mysql database from localhost anymore as localhost means pointing to your container. Since mysql is running on your host machine, you can refer it by using *host.docker.internal* instead of localhost in connection string.

So you connection string should be

`spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://host.docker.internal:3309/library`

Comment: I tried this and I'm still getting a connection error. I don't understand how the image can be built if I'm unable to connect to the SQL db since Spring attempts to run the app before producing a jar.

Comment: Ideally build shouldn't be dependent on SQL connection. It could be possible your unit tests are written against MySQL. Could you pls share the logs of what the error you are facing?

Comment: I got it. Thank you for your help.
this vid helped -> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PAQvxqocb6A